# What is the complexity of Ruby's Array#insert?

Tags: ruby

What is the complexity of Ruby's Array#insert?

Is it O(1) or O(n) (memory is copied)?

Comment: check out the code : https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d917e65143f08c88b1c83a71132b66c0a4c2db87/array.c#L1639

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple benchmark shows that insert is `O(n)`:

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  arr = (1..10000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.insert(1, 1)} }
  arr = (1..100000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.insert(1, 1)} }
  arr = (1..1000000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.insert(1, 1)} }
end

     user     system      total        real
 0.078000   0.000000   0.078000 (  0.077023)
 0.500000   0.000000   0.500000 (  0.522345)
 5.953000   0.000000   5.953000 (  5.967949)
```

As long as you don't push to the end of the array, when it becomes `O(1)`:

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  arr = (1..10000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.push 1} }
  arr = (1..100000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.push 1} }
  arr = (1..1000000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.push 1} }
  arr = (1..10000000).to_a
  x.report { 10000.times {arr.push 1} }
end

   user     system      total        real
 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001002)
 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001000)
 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001001)
 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002001)
```